# SLES 12 SP1 expired letsencrypt X3 root ca certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate-errors, zypper, sles12

I'm working with SLES 12 SP1.

When running

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Factory/standard/openSUSE:Factory.repo
```

I get the following error

```
Download (curl) error for 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Factory/standard/openSUSE:Factory.repo':
Error code: Unrecognized error
Error message: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Debugging with

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect download.opensuse.org:443 -debug -servername download.opensuse.org
```

I see the following

```
...

depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0

...

---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=opensuse.org
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
   i:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/CN=opensuse.org
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5308 bytes and written 485 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 658EF2FD83D487DD3FE9BCB345550A490CE6693B8808F3BA4B1CB6879597E898
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 968B034D2679BDDFDBB90467572409C4016CC78F8947EE5C7AD02368A5AB864C3530491003A39D00D544C128D45BF28C
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - dd 67 ca b4 ec 1f ab 4e-6c f0 31 23 9f b3 07 c0   .g.....Nl.1#....
    0010 - c4 33 d7 8e 95 ce 43 23-26 17 bd 2b c2 25 37 78   .3....C#&..+.%7x
    0020 - 2f fd ba b8 f1 b2 7f 5d-d1 c6 19 66 95 3f 92 ab   /......]...f.?..
    0030 - 4a 4c 41 4b af 3b 75 b7-80 27 67 61 fa f3 e3 06   JLAK.;u..'ga....
    0040 - 81 9b cf c6 1b 3c 9f 0b-3b 51 d1 f8 67 13 4a 2c   .....<..;Q..g.J,
    0050 - 13 e6 cc 8b 34 e0 44 e4-0f 7e 7a 03 92 2c 52 07   ....4.D..~z..,R.
    0060 - e8 7d ed 7f 65 42 b0 6f-73 10 68 a2 f6 eb 45 9f   .}..eB.os.h...E.
    0070 - 8d eb e8 d7 90 2a 88 37-87 a2 48 91 70 36 e2 14   .....*.7..H.p6..
    0080 - f6 17 50 56 d6 0f c5 02-a6 09 88 2b d5 aa 4d d2   ..PV.......+..M.
    0090 - fe 8c 18 ad 5d 29 b6 ce-d3 eb a3 8e c4 72 ec 32   ....]).......r.2
    00a0 - 61 30 a9 60 ea d4 48 15-cf e5 b7 25 be 95 9f d5   a0.`..H....%....
    00b0 - a7 b0 17 c8 07 e4 7b 4e-df ee fa 8b f5 1e 7f a1   ......{N........
    00c0 - 11 da 92 d2 2b 6e 6a d2-60 ed ff 9f 2c a7 c7 d9   ....+nj.`...,...

    Start Time: 1680875176
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
...
```

How can I fix this certificate issue in order to be able to add the repo?

Comment: Is SLES up-to-date? It feels like its system trust store hasn't been updated in ages.